# Show that a martingale is not $L^1$ convergent

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, random-walk, infinite-product

Consider the symmetric random walk $S_n$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.

The process $Z_n=\exp(uS_n-n \ \log(\cosh(u)))$ for $u\in \mathbb{R}$ is a positive martingale with $E(Z_n)=1$ for all $n\geq 1$.

$Z_n$ is $L^1$ bounded and with Doob's martingale convergence theorem we get that $Z_n$ converges a.s. to an integrable random variable $Z_\infty$.

How can we prove that $Z_\infty=0$ a.s. for $u\not=0$ which would mean that $Z_n$ is not $L^1$ convergent?

I tried using the Borel Cantelli lemma but I am not sure if that is the right way.

I also tried the direct method and compute $E(\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_n)$ but I am stuck at $E(\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pi_{k=1}^n \exp(uX_k))\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \cosh(u)^{-n}$ and used Fatou's lemma to get that the expectation is less or equal than $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cosh(u)^n$. That only gives that $E(Z_\infty)\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $n^{-1}\log Z_n$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't see it. This approaches $-\log(\cosh(u))$ a.s. because of the SLLN. What does this give us?

Comment: Notice that $-\log\cosh u<0$.  What happens to $\log Z_n$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I think $\log Z_n \to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty$ so $Z_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Precisely.  And that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. That's a nice proof!